# How to configure ingress to deploy services to subdomains without creating a new loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am new to Kubernetes and have an application deployed via GKE on mydomain.com and now want to add another service which should be available on api.mydomain.com without adding a new expensive load balancer. What should the new ingress file for api.mydomain look like? I read the documentation, but cannot figure out how to do this.

This is my first service running on mydomain.com:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "ip"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: my-certs
```

I tried to use the same configuration for the subdomain api.mydomain.com, but this does not work.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "ip"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.mydomain.com
    secretName: my-certs-api
```

Maybe I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way, I'm new in GKE, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "nginx" ingress.class . The config shall be like the following (I have removed tls part out it).

[Nginx Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/) 
is quite easy and functional.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: double-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
#    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2  ### you can use it to route different paths to different services under the same host
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
#      - path: /doc/common(/|$)(.*)    ### if you are using rewrite
        backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 80

  - host: api.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: api-service
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.mydomain.com
    secretName: my-certs-api
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Multi-tls usage example: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/7627757081ee8a75eccf1a9fbeb3cac2f6cce7d1/docs/examples/multi-tls/multi-tls.yaml#L95

Answer (score 1):

You would generally use a different Ingress Controller than the default ingress-gce. ingress-nginx is very common and easy to get started with, but there are many options so I recommend you research them and pick which one matches your use case best.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into nginx

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to create one HTTP load balancer with one public IP address for two different domains.

It's doable using standard GKE  ingress controller [GCE L7](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) at least for HTTP protocol (see example below).

Please also find [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl) about using multiple SSL certificates with GCE L7 ingress.

Example:
*( mydomain.com is replaced with example.com, [because...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke) an answer body cannot contain it.)*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 80
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Applying this yaml to GKE cluster results creating one HTTP load-balancer with the following Host and path rules:

```
http://example.com:80/* -> app-service:80 (if app-service health-check passed)
http://example.com:80/* -> default-backend:80 (return 404) (if app-service heath-check fails and default-backend health-check passed)
http://api.example.com:80/* -> api-service:80 (if app-service health-check passed)
http://api.example.com:80/* -> default-backend:80 (return 404) (if api-service heath-check fails and default-backend health-check passed)
http://lb.ip.address:80 -> default-backend:80 (return 404) (if  default-backend health-check passed)

HTTP LB returns 502 if all backends' health-checks are failed.
```